# Supporting different Shapes in ButtonStyle

Tags: ios, swift, button, swiftui

I'm creating a `Button` with a custom `ButtonStyle`. I'd like this button style to support two different “appearances” - circular or rounded rectangle. To do this, I have defined an enum for the appearance cases and pass that through to the `ButtonStyle` so it can modify its properties as needed. I've run into a problem and that is trying to provide different `Shape`s to `clipShape()`. There's a compile-time error where I return some `Shape`:

> Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in
>   its body do not have matching underlying types

What’s a good approach to resolve this error and implement the desired button appearances?

```
struct FloatingButton: View {
    enum FloatingButtonStyleType {
        case circle
        case roundedRectangle
    }

    private let image: Image
    private let style: FloatingButtonStyleType
    private let action: () -> ()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            image
        }
        .buttonStyle(FloatingButtonStyle(style: style))
    }

    init(image: Image, style: FloatingButtonStyleType, action: @escaping () -> ()) {
        self.image = image
        self.style = style
        self.action = action
    }
}

struct FloatingButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let style: FloatingButton.FloatingButtonStyleType

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding(.all, 10)
            .background(Color.black)
            .clipShape(clipShape())
    }

    private func clipShape() -> some Shape { //FIXME: Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types
        switch style {
        case .circle:
            return Circle()
        case .roundedRectangle:
            return RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible approach (compiled & worked, tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2)

```
struct FloatingButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let style: FloatingButton.FloatingButtonStyleType

    struct StyleModifier : ViewModifier {
        let style: FloatingButton.FloatingButtonStyleType

        func body(content: Self.Content) -> AnyView {
            switch style {
            case .circle:
                return AnyView(content.clipShape(Circle()))
            case .roundedRectangle:
                return AnyView(content.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, 
                               style: .continuous)))
            }
        }
    }

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .padding(.all, 10)
            .background(Color.black)
            .modifier(StyleModifier(style: style))
    }

}
```